# For XMLparser in xCode, what string name do i test against?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-parsing

I've been reading up on XML and still can't figure this part. It's complicated because there are more than one similar line. For this second line from the xml file how do i test the elementName? "link" doesn't work, nor "preview" nor lots of others i tried

XML file:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/do-not-press-the-red-button/id317885341?mt=8&amp;uo=2"/>

<link title="Preview" rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://abc.jpg" im:assetType="preview"><im:duration>0</im:duration></link>
```

Xcode project:

```
static NSString *kImageStr = @"link";
if ([elementName isEqualToString:kImageStr]){
    //parse it
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you yourself are creating this XML than you can use namespaces for it else you will have to distinguish between the elements depending upon the attributes....

in the didStartElement..

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){

    NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"];
 }
```

and by the way @"link" should work according to me...